# Biztalk Map node validation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-mapper

I'm mapping home, work and mobile number nodes from the source schema to the home, work and mobile node in the destination schema.

I need to ensure that the data matches destination pattern (No space, punctuation, leading zeros, matching `[+0][0-9]*`. Can this be achieved via `XSLT`?

### Source

```
<HTelephone>01656 123 123</HTelephone>
<WTelephone>01656-123-123</WTelephone>
<MTelephone>+447656 123 123</MTelephone>
```

### Destination

```
<HTelephone>01656123123</HTelephone>
<WTelephone>01656123123</WTelephone>
<MTelephone>+447656123123</MTelephone>
```

### Current Inline XSLT Call Template

```
<xsl:template name="MNo" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" >
 <xsl:param name="inTelNo"/>
 <xsl:element name="MTelephone" >
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('+', translate($inTelNo, translate($inTelNo,'0123456789',''), ''))"/>
 </xsl:element>
```

We need to validation the first character to allow a 0 or + also, any ideas?

Comment: Sure, this can be done. To get a specific answer you'd have to ask a specific question (i.e. include input XML, your attempted XSLT and the XML output you expect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming correct input ( a root element to make it well-formed XML) use the `concat()` and `translate` functions to change the strings.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <HTelephone>01656 123 123</HTelephone>
    <WTelephone>01656 123 123</WTelephone>
    <MTelephone>01656 123 123</MTelephone>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('+',translate(.,' ',''))"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <HTelephone>+01656123123</HTelephone>
   <WTelephone>+01656123123</WTelephone>
   <MTelephone>+01656123123</MTelephone>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, I'm trying to fit this into my existing map around the xslt already generated when validating the map. The section of code I have found has been amended to the question.

Comment: @PuffTMD I have absolutely no idea what you added to your question and how it relates to your question or to my solution. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've added an extract from the xlst for the section of code that is currently mapping the phone numbers with a default value.  I'll need to replace this with the answer you have provided but unsure if i just add in the node with the concat/translate...

Comment: @PuffTMD It is impossible to say how you should integrate this in your existing stylesheet. For starters, how can I know what those variables mean or what template match this tiny snippet is in?

Comment: Thanks I'll keep at it.

Comment: Been trying to get this working with the inline this is what i have, but it's not working any help appreciated. '<xsl:element name="Rootname/Section/ContactDetails/HomeTelephone">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('+',translate(.,' ',''))"/>'.

Comment: @PuffTMD "It's not working" is never an accurate description of an error. What do you mean by that?

Comment: the inline code added above is not being executed in the ouput window.  I'm not sure if I have that inline xslt code correct so was hoping to have any help around that.

Comment: I've updated the main feed with new information, I now need to check the first two characters compared to the remaining criteria.  any idears